# Can $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Hadamard product be represented as matrices?

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, hypercomplex-numbers

It is known that $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Hadamard product, represented as pairs or numbers $(a,b)$ with element-wise operations is isomorphic to real matrices of the form $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{a+b}{2} & \frac{a-b}{2} \\
 \frac{a-b}{2} & \frac{a+b}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$, and also to the split-complex numbers.

But I wonder, whether it is possible to represent $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Hadamard product and element-wise operations as real matrices in a similar way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for complex matrices.  Let $\omega = \exp(i 2\pi/3)$ be a primitive cube root of $1$.  Define
$$
H(a,b,c) :=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{a+b+c}{3} & \frac{a+\omega b+\omega^2 c}{3} &
 \frac{a+\omega^2 b+\omega c}{3}
\\
\frac{a+\omega^2 b+\omega c}{3} & \frac{a+b+c}{3} &
\frac{a+\omega b+\omega^2 c}{3}
\\
\frac{a+\omega b+\omega^2 c}{3} & \frac{a+\omega^2 b+\omega c}{3} & \frac{a+b+c}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then
$$
H(a,b,c)+ H(d,e,f) = H(a+d,b+e,c+f)
\\
H(a,b,c) H(d,e,f) = H(ad,be,cf)
$$

Probably we can adapt this to get real $6 \times 6$ matrices, replacing each complex number by a real $2\times 2$ matrix in the usual way.

Comment: And what would be the analog of split-complex basis $\frac{a+b}{2}+j\frac{a-b}{2}$?

Comment: Something like $\frac{a+b+c}{3}+j_1 \frac{a+\omega b+\omega^2 c}{3}+j_2 \frac{a+\omega^2 b+\omega c}{3}$? And accounting for the complex nature of the coefficients, this will be a 6-dimensinal system? I wonder, what would be the algebraic properties?

Comment: But the original $\mathbb{R}^3$ is 3-dimensional and itself can be considered a 3D hypercomplex number system with everything in it already. I am just in search for more canonical orthogonal basis with multiplicative identity as one basis vector. Is it possible?